# pickup latest files from a windows directory and scp to linux server

Tags: java, linux, scripting, automation, scp

I have a directory say BuildArea on a windows machine under which i have multiple folders say lib , applications, etc.
when we build java files..respective jar files are placed in lib folder and war/ear files in applications folder.

I want to automate the scp of these files on to a linux server.
The challenge i am facing here is to pick up the latest built jar/ear/war files because the respective folders have many other such files.

For example: lib will have a.jar, b.jar and so on. Let's say i just build latest version of a.jar then i need to pick up only this latest a.jar

I initially thought of below:

step 1)
creating a script that will accept arguments from an input text file which will have a list of recently built artifact names and this script will copy these files into a separate directory. (say ReleaseArea)

step 2)
another script to scp the files copied in ReleaseArea folder using above script on to linux server.

However, this involves manual intervention and would like to have a more efficient way.

Suggestions / best practices always welcome.

Thanks and Regards,

Rohan

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a script that find newly generated file (like 60min ago for instance) using find command like this :

```
find /BuildArea -mmin 60 -exec scp {} @server:/destination/path \;
```

However if you want to use scp from the linux host I assume you have a ssh server on Windows host so you could use ssh to execute last command remotely then put the script in a cron job that would be run say every hour.